# How to find if mail delivery succeeded or not using javax.mail api if recipient mail id doesnot exist

Tags: java, jsp, email, jakarta-mail

I am working on sending a mail to a recipient in jsp and servlets,
I am using javax.mail api for this. 
I need to send an auto generated email which cant be replied back.
Can i achieve this using javax.mail api? i am setting 'from' as some dummy mail address for now so the recipient cant reply back right? Is there any other way or doing this???

secondly, in case if the recipient mail id doesnt exist, i am not getting any MessagingException. How to check whether message delivered or not? how can i confirm that?

Need your help! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you don't have control of checking weather the message was successfully delivered or not, there are some tricky way to do it by tokanizing a get with a transparent little image and tracking, See: http://superuser.com/questions/142062/how-mail-tracking-works

Comment: @Jigar Joshi- Thanks for the reply. This will work only when the message is opened by the reciever right? Any way to check the delivery of the mail alone. ? using some other mail api? and regarding the auto generated mails, am i correct in my approach..

Comment: no you can't know what are the valid emails for `@xml.com`

Comment: I want to catch exceptions in case of such mail address- invalid@gmail.com , invalid@invalid.com, invalid@invalid.invalid. I guess its not possible by what you say. . Anyways thanks Jigar. Any suggestions on auto generated mails?

Comment: autogenerated mails ?

Comment: like the ones where you will have some text like " THIS IS AN AUTO GENERATED EMAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY" and all.. i want to achieve something like that. where the receiver cant reply back.